# Quick and efficient way to create graphs from a list of list

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

I want to generate a list of edges from a list: 
(the size of the list can be changed, just 4 for this example)

[image]

From the list above, I can generate 24 permutations like this.

```
mylist = Permutations[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}]
```

Now I want to convert each list in `mylist` into graph as I mentioned above. I could do this by writing a function like this:

```
myfunc[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, {e_, f_}, {g_, 
     h_}}] := {b \[UndirectedEdge] c, d \[UndirectedEdge] e, 
   f \[UndirectedEdge] g, h \[UndirectedEdge] a};
```

However, I'm looking for something which is fast, efficient and can work with any number of elements (not just 4 as above). 
Any idea to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear[myfunc];

myfunc[list_] := 
  UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[RotateLeft[Flatten[list], 1], 2]

myfunc /@ mylist
(* { {b \[UndirectedEdge] c, d \[UndirectedEdge] e, f \[UndirectedEdge] g,
      h \[UndirectedEdge] a}, ...} *)
```

Comment: I think you misread my rule to convert the list to graph. `{{a, b}, {c, d}}` would be converted to `{b-c, d-a}`  with`-` is for undirected edge.

Comment: Oh, sorry I had two functions with the same name so it was confusing.

Comment: It does that, but it was meant to accept the whole ``mylist``. I changed it now to a single-list function.

Comment: Simplifying: `UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[RotateLeft@Catenate@#, 2] &`

Answer (score 3):

Or using `SubsetMap`. After we get one `graph`, we use `Permutations` to act on it to get anoter cases.

```
Clear[list,graph];
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};
graph = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
   Reverse /@ SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list, {All, 1}]

graph // Permutations
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just for fun.

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}} //
# /. {a_, e___} -> {a, e, a}& //
# //.{x___UndirectedEdge, {a_,b_},{c_,d_},e___} -> {x, UndirectedEdge[b,c], {c,d} ,e}& //
# /. {e___, a_} -> {e}&
```

> `{UndirectedEdge[b, c], UndirectedEdge[d, e], UndirectedEdge[f, g], UndirectedEdge[h, a]}`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};
```

---

```
MapThread[UndirectedEdge]@Reverse@MapAt[RotateRight, 2]@Transpose@list
```

---

Visualizing the code with `Echo`:

```
MapThread[UndirectedEdge]@
 Echo@Reverse@Echo@MapAt[RotateRight, 2]@Echo@Transpose@Echo@list
```

> list

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
 g & h \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

> Transpose

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & c & e & g \\
 b & d & f & h \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

> MapAt[RotateRight, 2]

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & c & e & g \\
 h & b & d & f \\
\ & \longrightarrow
\end{array}
\right) $$

> Reverse

$$ \left( \updownarrow
\begin{array}{cccc}
 h & b & d & f \\
 a & c & e & g \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

> MapThread[UndirectedEdge]

$$ \{h\longleftrightarrow a,b\longleftrightarrow c,d\longleftrightarrow e,f\longleftrightarrow g\} $$

**Note :** I used `/. UndirectedEdge -> LongLeftRightArrow` as `UndirectedEdge` does not render well here.